# openstreetmaps dll

Tags: dll, openstreetmap

I need to display OpenStreetMaps in application for desktop.
Is there some .dll to do it?

I'm trying to help a colleague who writes on C++, so tools for java are not suitable.

Comment: What do you want to display? Pre-rendered tiles? Self-rendered maps? Raw data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a DLL off-hand, although a few open source desktop viewers exist so there may be the possibility of encapsualing one of those in a DLL or otherwise communicating with it from a C++ application:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show a Web map or a vector map? In any case, [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net)'s map control can be embedded in a 3rd party app, but you will need a [commercial license](http://maperitive.net/docs/FAQ.html#Commercial%20use).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Maperitive.